# Join Table relationship in Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jboss

I have a basic question about Oracle Join tables. I am creating a Spring-based REST service using JBoss server & Hibernate.

I have two tables used for Basic Auth: Users & Roles, which have a **bi-directional Many-to-Many relationship**. So i have created three tables:

- `Users`
- `Roles`
- `Users_Roles`

How should I create the relationships - also which would give better performance?

- Using foreign key relation while creating the table?
- Using `@JoinTable` annotation in entity class?

(The above is just one example, but I have handful of large tables like this.)

Forgive me if my understanding above both option is wrong. I am newbie to Hibernate & Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for formatting and added clarification!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a primary key constraint for user_roles that has both "user id" and "role id".  further, there would be two foreign key constraints on user_roles, one to user table and one to roles table.

Comment: So you suggestion me to go with Jointable creation in oracle itself. Instead of using @ JoinTable in entity class. How about performance in those option?